# Button size becomes small in iphone sdk 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uibutton

I have done one app in iphone sdk 3.0 in that i use some buttons in 3.0 size of button are fine but when i use that app in iphone sdk4.0.That time, size of button becomes small.The same button code works in 3.0 but not in 4.0.Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample code would help.  In general for iPhone 4 you just make a button image with twice the size and add "@2x" to the name, this will automatically be used for Retina display.  So you would have "button.png" and "button@2x.png" in your project.